# How to update a field in an entire collection in mongodb using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a collection named TeamInfo, I created a class for it in java using morphia's annotations as follows:

```
@Entity("TeamInfo ")
public class TeamInfo {
    @Id
    private Integer teamInfoId;
    private String teamName;
    private Integer userCount;
}
```

I need to do an update operation on TeamInfo which changes the userCount and sets it to 0. I need a query which will set the userCount value in all the TeamInfo documents. So how to get all the TeamInfo documents in the query?

```
UpdateOperations<TeamInfo> updateOperation = datastore.createUpdateOperations(TeamInfo.class).set("userCount", 0);        
Query<TeamInfo> query = datastore. ??? ;
datastore.update(query, updateOperation);
```

I just started learning morphia, it will be great if someone can help me.

Comment: I am trying to perform an update operation(SQL) similar to this in mongoDB:   `Query query = em.createQuery("UPDATE TeamInfo t SET t.userCount=0");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use empty query without any condition.

```
UpdateOperations<TeamInfo> updateOperation = datastore.createUpdateOperations(TeamInfo.class).set("userCount", 0);        
Query<TeamInfo> query = datastore.createQuery(getEntityClazz()); // empty query
datastore.update(query, updateOperation);
```